# Why wheel nuts further away from the centre don't increase torque?

Tags: torque

I'm learning about torque right now, and I get that at a constant force, torque increases with distance from the axis of rotation.

[image: wheel hub picture]

This got me thinking about the hub of a car. As far as I can tell, only wheel nuts apply a force on the wheel which provide the torque and cause it to rotate. Hence, I would think that having wheel nuts further away from the centre should increase the torque of wheels. However, I am guessing that there must be a gap in my understanding as I would think that all cars would have wheel nuts in such an arrangement if this really was the case.

I also started having a look at some f1 hubs, where the whole point of the car is to maximise torque. Wheel rim sizes were increased from 2021 to 2022 so this would allow a larger wheel hub, which according to my probably flawed logic, would cause larger torque in 2022 cars compared to 2021, which I don't think is what has happened.

Hence, essentially I am aksing if someone can explain the flaw in my understanding, i.e. the reason wheel nuts further from the axis of rotation don't increase torque.

Answer (score 0):

The drive torque is supplied by the engine through the drive shaft, into the axle, through the wheel bolts/nuts, and then through the tire to the ground.

So the torque to the wheel is not affected by the diameter to the wheel nuts, but is instead the same as the engine torque (with friction losses along the way).

The only advantage of having the nuts at a larger diameter is that the load on each nut will be smaller.  In other words, if the diameter is too small, then the bolts would break.

Your question is similar to asking... "Thick ropes can lift more weight, so why aren't all ropes thicker?"